# random.Next() not returning random only returning 0 - C#

Tags: c#, random

I'm sure this will get marked as a duplicate, but I genuinely have tried to figure this out. Here goes nothing.

I have come across a problem while working through an exercise in Head First C#. My problem is my random.Next(2) in my Move() method will only return 0. Here is the condensed code:

```
public class Opponent
    {
        private Location myLocation;
        private Random random;
        public bool Hidden { get; private set; }

        public Opponent(Location startingLocation)
        {
            myLocation = startingLocation;
            random = new Random();
            Hidden = false;
        }

        public void Move()
        {
            var coinFlip = random.Next(2);

            if (myLocation is IHasExteriorDoor)
            {
                if (coinFlip == 1)
                {
                    var myLocationWithDoor = (IHasExteriorDoor)myLocation;
                    myLocation = myLocationWithDoor.DoorLocation;
                }
            }

            myLocation = myLocation.Exits[random.Next(myLocation.Exits.Length)];
            while (!(myLocation is IHidingPlace))
            {
                myLocation = myLocation.Exits[random.Next(myLocation.Exits.Length)];
            }

            Hidden = true;
        }
    }
```

I have tried moving the random.Next() around, putting it directly in the if statement, but that didn't change anything.

I also replaced my code with the code from the book and that seems to work. The only problem is I truly do not see the difference. Here is the Move() method the book provided.

```
public void Move()
    {
        bool hidden = false;
        while (!hidden)
        {
            if (myLocation is IHasExteriorDoor)
            {
                IHasExteriorDoor locationWithDoor =
                                myLocation as IHasExteriorDoor;
                if (random.Next(2) == 1)
                    myLocation = locationWithDoor.DoorLocation;
            }
            int rand = random.Next(myLocation.Exits.Length);
            myLocation = myLocation.Exits[rand];
            if (myLocation is IHidingPlace)
                hidden = true;
        }
    }
```

I don't really understand why that random.Next() will give me 1 and 0 but mine will not.

I've tried to do some googling and I have found a bunch of folks having issues with threading. Where they are creating multiple Random objects that end up with the same seed, thus receiving identical random numbers. However, I don't think that is what is happening here.

Any insight on what is happening here? This is the link to my [GitHub](https://github.com/talbert1209/HideAndSeek) so you can see the whole project if that helps.

Thank you in advance for the help!

Comment: Does `random.Next(myLocation.Exits.Length)` also return 0?

Comment: @ikerbera no, that is working as expected. Which confuses me even more.

Comment: How many times have you tested that? Try to do some test looping the `Move()` method and logging the coinFlip value. Sree if it's always returning 0 or you're being unlucky.

Comment: Just to cover all bases...does it make it into `if (myLocation is IHasExteriorDoor)`?  How do you instantiate Opponent, and how are you testing Move()?  Are you calling it in a loop somewhere?

Comment: Do you really need a separate instance of `Random` for each `Opponent`? Or would `private static Random random = new Random();` suffice? -- If you instantiate "all" the `Opponents` in a tight loop, they'll all get the same seed value and they will all produce the same "random" sequence.

Comment: @Corak I can give that a try, but only 1 opponent is used in the program. The issues isn't multiple instances of Random... At least I don't think. I guess I should have explained this better in my post, but basically what happens is when I tell the opponent to hide by clicking the hide button the opponent first uses random.Next to decide weather to be inside or outside. The opponent has never gone inside yet.

Comment: @BenKrueger Yes. I start the program in a location that will always be IHasExteriorDoor. So basically when I click the hide button, the opponent first decides if they should hide inside or outside based on the random.next() result.

Comment: @Talbert1209 Have you actually debugged the code and seen that the actual random value is always 0, or are you just assuming that based on the results?

Comment: @juharr I am assuming based on using the program and putting a watch on coinFlip. I have done it 20 times and have never seen it return 1. However, after about 3 attempts I saw random.Next(2) return 1 when using my books solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm really sorry. This is embarrassing. My problem was that I had my break point on the line with the random.Next(2) so every time I checked it it was always zero. Again super sorry to waste people's time and thanks for the suggestions.

Comment: We've all been there.  Thanks for coming back with your discovery statement.